# How to see gitlab users by command?

Tags: gitlab

I installed gitlab on ubuntu, how can I  see gitlab users by command?

Following command find root user , but I do not know user name?

```
user = User.find_by(username: "root")
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to find user.
If you forget root password you can find it by ID

```
user = User.find(1)
```

Gitlab support Find the user either by username, user ID or email ID:

```
user = User.find_by_username 'exampleuser'
#or
user = User.find(123)
#or
user = User.find_by(email: 'user@example.com')
```

documentary in [docs.gitlab.com/reset_user_password](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/reset_user_password.html)

Comment: In ubuntu you can see log gitlab by command. "sudo gitlab-ctl tail" or check file production.log in /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production. log

Comment: user = User.find(1) returns nil, what is problem?I want see all users without findby(id)

Comment: User.find(1) returns nil. This proves that you have installed Gitlab errors. There should be any Users including User Root, You Can Check Log For More Information.

Comment: what is result of command "sudo gitlab-ctl status" and "sudo gitlab-ctl tail"

Answer (score 0):

**#git config —global —list**

To list the user associated with github/gitlab

Answer (score 0):

To find all users:

```
> user=User.all
```

To  get there use the gitlab-rails console

```
sudo gitlab-rails console
```

Quit the console with 'quit'. Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.